# How to AccessPower BI Admin API from C# App

Tags: azure, authentication, powerbi, authorization

Context: I'm NOT an Azure user nor a PowerBI user, but I've been task with getting the Data Lineage information out of Power BI to reverse engineer into our Metadata Repository.

Firstly, can anyone confirm that it is possible to connect to the Power BI Admin API using AppOnly Authentication (as of the date of the question)?

Secondly, we're using the older ADAL flow (rather than the newer, and recommended, MSAL flow - because that's what the sample we obtained used) which is deprecated but, I believe, should still work.  We've slowly been rectifying the authentication/authorisation issues and have now got as far as getting the authentication token.  However, when we try to call the API ("https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/reports") we get the "API is not accessible for application".

We believe we have the full complement of permissions... Power BI Service (15).

Can anyone shed light on where to look next for the issue?

Does any kind soul have a sample app to provide which accesses the Power BI Admin API?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to call the admin API from C# application using ADAL. Show us your code.

Comment: Just Copy &  paste it?

Comment: Also, we can use MSAL yes?

Comment: Create [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what is wrong with your code and tell you how to fix it. Yes, you can use MSAL too.

Comment: OK, so here's the deal...

Comment: In trying to create the Minimal Reproducible example, it suddenly seemed to start working!  I am now getting a response that appears to contain the list of reports I'm after.  How do I upload the file so you can see it?

Comment: You should edit your question to include the code, but why doing it if it works? We can't debug your product.